# stored proc does not return result but putting it as query does

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which goes like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[solar_zip_affiliate_export]
  @affiliate_id int,
  @tier_date varchar
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

select   zip, MAX(state) as state from solar_zip_tier_mapping_view sztm (nolock) 
join solar_zip_tier_acl acl (nolock) on acl.tier_id = sztm.tier_id and (acl.buyer_id = sztm.buyer_id or acl.buyer_id = 0)
join buyers b (nolock) on b.buyer_id = sztm.buyer_id
join solar_zip_tiers szt (nolock) on szt.tier_id = sztm.tier_id
where sztm.tier_date = @tier_date and acl.affiliate_id = @affiliate_id and sztm.active > 0 and b.active > 0 and szt.active > 0
group by zip 

END
```

Now when I call this stored procedure as

```
 exec solar_zip_affiliate_export 150, '021516'"
```

it does not return any results, but if I replace parameter with actual value and run it as query( means just get the select part and run it separately in management studio) it gives proper result.
I'm going nuts. 
Please any help

Comment: You should really use a date field for storing dates, not a varchar.

Comment: If you are going to insist on using that NOLOCK hint then you at least to include the WITH keyword. Omitting it has been deprecated. I would argue you should not litter your database with that hint unless you really know what it does. It is not as simple as just dirty reads. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[solar_zip_affiliate_export]
@affiliate_id int,
@tier_date varchar(20)  --<-- you need to define the length here 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

select   zip, MAX(state) as state from solar_zip_tier_mapping_view sztm (nolock) 
join solar_zip_tier_acl acl (nolock) on acl.tier_id = sztm.tier_id and (acl.buyer_id = sztm.buyer_id or acl.buyer_id = 0)
join buyers b (nolock) on b.buyer_id = sztm.buyer_id
join solar_zip_tiers szt (nolock) on szt.tier_id = sztm.tier_id
where sztm.tier_date = @tier_date and acl.affiliate_id = @affiliate_id and sztm.active > 0 and b.active > 0 and szt.active > 0
group by zip
```

If you do not define the length it is default to `1` hence always explicitly define the length for variables with data type varchar, nvarchar, char, nchar etc.